# Using flexboxes to create boxes in the right places

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to achieve the following design:

[image]

I was suggested to use Flexbox for that. I have tried some approaches, but I can't seem to understand how to keep the same size of the boxes. I have a field `data` which contains all the the need data:

```
[
  {
    "name": "action",
    "img": "action.jpg",
    "status": "NO"
  }
  {
    "name": "Aldi",
    "img": "aldi.jpg",
    "status": "YES"
  }
]
```

But I really struggle with the CSS part. I can't seem to understand how to keep the boxes separated. I have created the main div that will hold the gray background. Then I tried to loop though the data and create a a flexbox for each one but it does not create those boxes right. I feel like I approach this problem wrong. Is it possible to show how to create those boxes for each one of the data elements? Please don't show how to create the button, i'll try myself, I just struggle with the body of those blocks.

Comment: Try using vuejs bootstrap card - https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/card

Comment: This should be a few lines, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me you have something like this. 
Note that you will need to adjust `flex` property on different screen sizes. Bootstrap `row` and `columns` can help if you are using it in the project.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.item {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  list-style: none;
}

.item > div {
  height: 120px;
  margin: 1rem; 
  background: rgba(250, 250, 250, 1);
}
```

```html
<ul class="wrapper">
  <li class="item">
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <div></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```